# read and write with lil_matrix

Tags: python, methods, scipy, sparse-matrix

I need to read and write easily on a lil_matrix structure.
Briefly, given an index i:

- I need to get row_i, i.e., `mat[i,:]`, which is easily done with `mat.getrow(i)` for lil_matrix
- I need to extract a value from this row, e.g `row[j]`, but I do not see methods for doing so
- I need to modify some values of this row, e.g `row[j] = N`, but also here, no method are available
- I theen need to get the position of the nonzero elements, so `row.nonzero()`, but then I must maintain the sparse format until here, and also extract this nonzero elements.

To be clearer, I need to maintain the lil_matrix format through each step of it, without making the structure full.

any clue ?

Comment: While I could walk you through some steps of what I think you want, it would be better if you demonstrated with a real small example.  Show what you have accomplished, and explain how that falls short of your goals.  Keep in mind that `lil` format does allow indexing that looks nearly the same as `ndarray`.  Also `mat.data` and `mat.rows` store the actually matrix values.